# $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is not equinumerous to $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble proving that the sets $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ have different cardinalities.

What I tried to do: I assumed there exists a function $F:$ $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}\to$ $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ which is onto $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. I then tried using Cantor's diagonal argument to disprove the claim, however, I cannot find (or build) a function which belongs to $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ but doesn't belong to the image of $F$. To elaborate: Since $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable, I assumed there is an index set $I$ which is equivalent to it. Then, for each  $i\in I$ there is a function $f_i\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}\to$ $F(f_i)=m_i$ where $m_i\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ (Assuming that $I$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$) . How can I build a function $b\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ that is not equal to all $m_i,\ \ i\in I$ using Cantor's diagonal argument? Is there a specific choice for $I$ which would make the problem easier?

Would appreciate any help and hints.

Comment: What does equivalent mean?

Comment: I haven't learned about cardinality yet, but I'm trying to prove that the cardinalty of {0,1}^N is smaller than the cardinality of N^N, or that there doesn't exist a one-to-one function onto N^N (whose domain is {0,1}^N)

Comment: Why are you trying to prove this? (Meaning: Why do you think this is true?)

Comment: The question was to check whether both sets are not equivalent. I tried to prove it for I had no idea regarding how to disprove it. If they are equivalent, how can I prove that? (if you could give me a hint)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093259/power-of-sets-0-1-mathbbn-simeq-mathbbn-mathbbn and other related questions. You can find some of them [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/183513), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/14429) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/110211).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\Bbb{N^N}$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(\Bbb{N\times N})$. Now use the fact that $\mathcal P(\Bbb{N\times N})$ and $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: From what I learned, since {0,1}^N is equivalent to P(N) (there is a one-to-one and onto function between them) then P(NxN) and {0,1}^N have the same cardinality. And since N^N is a subset of P(NxN) then its cardinality is smaller or equal to P(NxN)'s cardinality. That means N^N's cardinality is smaller or equal to {0,1}^N's cardinality. How do I continue from here?

Comment: Do you know about the Cantor-Bernstein theorem?

Comment: No sir, but I will read about it I guess, thanks. Just to be sure, the sets are not equivalent, right?

Comment: They are equivalent.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot.

Comment: I have seen a text where it was called the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem and another that called it the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem

Comment: Yes, @user254665, this theorem has several names.